# SciPy Hierarchical String Clustering in Python?

Tags: python, string, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

In one of my previous Stack Overflow questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101659/algorithm-to-to-cluster-similar-strings-in-python/49125567#49125567)), I was recommended to use Hierarchical Clustering to group strings contained in a list based on Hamming distance. I found several other posters who had questions about Python SciPy package, specifically, the linkage functions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949795/string-clustering-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707062/text-clustering-using-scipy-hierarchy-clustering-in-python)) who had similar problems to mine.

If my understanding of SciPy's linkage function is correct, I need to pass in an array and specify linkage to cluster based on Hamming distance. However, when I try to implement this on a list of several strings:

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
X = [[i] for i in ['apples','applez','appelz','apppel','orange','oranze','oranqg','orangs']]
Z = sch.linkage(X,method='complete',metric='Hamming')
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/nguyenthoh/Desktop/UMI_grouping/scratch_script.py", line 15, in <module>
Z = sch.linkage(X,method='complete',metric='Hamming')
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 694, in linkage
y = _convert_to_double(np.asarray(y, order='c'))
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 1216, in _convert_to_double
X = X.astype(np.double)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: apples
```

which obviously indicates that the input for linkage needs to be an array of numbers, not strings.

Is there a way to use strings with SciPy's linkage or do I need to provide a Hamming distance function with linkage so that it can cluster the strings?

Comment: Just act according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.hamming.html) and the [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L681-L720). The most important thing is how numpy treats ```u != v```. So, without evaluating anything about your task or approach: (0) check the validate-function (probably creating numpy array) (1) check what numpy does with ```u != v``` when u or v are object-arrays (from strings). (3) Don't use object-arrays.Naive approach: just convert your text to ascii-values (4)Keep in mind: #u = #v

Answer (score -1):

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: apples

You need to do label encoding for categorical variables with categories listed as strings (these could be also numbers typecasted as strings in python).

In python, we have: `from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder.`

Look at the documentation and implement it. It will label your string categories as an integer separately for each category.

Example:

> CODE: le.transform(["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"])
>  
>   OUTPUT: array([2, 2, 1]...)

Then you can use it for hierarchical/agglomerative clustering. 
Maybe also check that all the variables are in the numeric form such as int or float.

Have a nice day!